# Modify xsd not to look for specific order of tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd

I need to fix the error message below:
 Error occured while validating xmlThe element 'UserFields' has invalid child element 'LastApproverID'. List of possible elements expected: 'FirtApproverID'.

Below is my xsd for validating the xml schema :

```
<xs:element name="UserFields" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="FirtApproverID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                          <xs:element name="LastApproverID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
```

The order of the firstapproverid and lastapproverid does not matter but the tag need to occur atleast once.

i.e it can appear

```
<UserFields>
  <LastApproverID>123</LastApproverID> 
  <FirtApproverID>456</FirtApproverID> 
</UserFields>
```

**OR**

```
<UserFields>
    <FirtApproverID>456</FirtApproverID> 
  <LastApproverID>123</LastApproverID> 
</UserFields>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<xs:all>` indicator can solve your problem.

[See here for answer](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp)

Please, improve your Google skills.